# Calculating Modbus RTU CRC 16

Tags: c++, qt, hex, modbus, crc16

I'm implementing a software where I read and write data in Modbus RTU protocolo via serial. For that, I need to calculate the two CRC byte at the end of the string of bytes, but I'm being incapable of doing this.

Searching throughout the web, I found two functions that seems to calculate the CRC correctly:

```
WORD CRC16 (const BYTE *nData, WORD wLength)
{
    static const WORD wCRCTable[] = {
       0X0000, 0XC0C1, 0XC181, 0X0140, 0XC301, 0X03C0, 0X0280, 0XC241,
       0XC601, 0X06C0, 0X0780, 0XC741, 0X0500, 0XC5C1, 0XC481, 0X0440,
       0XCC01, 0X0CC0, 0X0D80, 0XCD41, 0X0F00, 0XCFC1, 0XCE81, 0X0E40,
       0X0A00, 0XCAC1, 0XCB81, 0X0B40, 0XC901, 0X09C0, 0X0880, 0XC841,
       0XD801, 0X18C0, 0X1980, 0XD941, 0X1B00, 0XDBC1, 0XDA81, 0X1A40,
       0X1E00, 0XDEC1, 0XDF81, 0X1F40, 0XDD01, 0X1DC0, 0X1C80, 0XDC41,
       0X1400, 0XD4C1, 0XD581, 0X1540, 0XD701, 0X17C0, 0X1680, 0XD641,
       0XD201, 0X12C0, 0X1380, 0XD341, 0X1100, 0XD1C1, 0XD081, 0X1040,
       0XF001, 0X30C0, 0X3180, 0XF141, 0X3300, 0XF3C1, 0XF281, 0X3240,
       0X3600, 0XF6C1, 0XF781, 0X3740, 0XF501, 0X35C0, 0X3480, 0XF441,
       0X3C00, 0XFCC1, 0XFD81, 0X3D40, 0XFF01, 0X3FC0, 0X3E80, 0XFE41,
       0XFA01, 0X3AC0, 0X3B80, 0XFB41, 0X3900, 0XF9C1, 0XF881, 0X3840,
       0X2800, 0XE8C1, 0XE981, 0X2940, 0XEB01, 0X2BC0, 0X2A80, 0XEA41,
       0XEE01, 0X2EC0, 0X2F80, 0XEF41, 0X2D00, 0XEDC1, 0XEC81, 0X2C40,
       0XE401, 0X24C0, 0X2580, 0XE541, 0X2700, 0XE7C1, 0XE681, 0X2640,
       0X2200, 0XE2C1, 0XE381, 0X2340, 0XE101, 0X21C0, 0X2080, 0XE041,
       0XA001, 0X60C0, 0X6180, 0XA141, 0X6300, 0XA3C1, 0XA281, 0X6240,
       0X6600, 0XA6C1, 0XA781, 0X6740, 0XA501, 0X65C0, 0X6480, 0XA441,
       0X6C00, 0XACC1, 0XAD81, 0X6D40, 0XAF01, 0X6FC0, 0X6E80, 0XAE41,
       0XAA01, 0X6AC0, 0X6B80, 0XAB41, 0X6900, 0XA9C1, 0XA881, 0X6840,
       0X7800, 0XB8C1, 0XB981, 0X7940, 0XBB01, 0X7BC0, 0X7A80, 0XBA41,
       0XBE01, 0X7EC0, 0X7F80, 0XBF41, 0X7D00, 0XBDC1, 0XBC81, 0X7C40,
       0XB401, 0X74C0, 0X7580, 0XB541, 0X7700, 0XB7C1, 0XB681, 0X7640,
       0X7200, 0XB2C1, 0XB381, 0X7340, 0XB101, 0X71C0, 0X7080, 0XB041,
       0X5000, 0X90C1, 0X9181, 0X5140, 0X9301, 0X53C0, 0X5280, 0X9241,
       0X9601, 0X56C0, 0X5780, 0X9741, 0X5500, 0X95C1, 0X9481, 0X5440,
       0X9C01, 0X5CC0, 0X5D80, 0X9D41, 0X5F00, 0X9FC1, 0X9E81, 0X5E40,
       0X5A00, 0X9AC1, 0X9B81, 0X5B40, 0X9901, 0X59C0, 0X5880, 0X9841,
       0X8801, 0X48C0, 0X4980, 0X8941, 0X4B00, 0X8BC1, 0X8A81, 0X4A40,
       0X4E00, 0X8EC1, 0X8F81, 0X4F40, 0X8D01, 0X4DC0, 0X4C80, 0X8C41,
       0X4400, 0X84C1, 0X8581, 0X4540, 0X8701, 0X47C0, 0X4680, 0X8641,
       0X8201, 0X42C0, 0X4380, 0X8341, 0X4100, 0X81C1, 0X8081, 0X4040 };

    BYTE nTemp;
    WORD wCRCWord = 0xFFFF;

    while (wLength--)
    {
        nTemp = *nData++ ^ wCRCWord;
        wCRCWord >>= 8;
        wCRCWord  ^= wCRCTable[nTemp];
    }
    return wCRCWord;
} // End: CRC16
```

And

```
uint CRC16_2(QByteArray buf, int len)
{
  uint crc = 0xFFFF;

  for (int pos = 0; pos < len; pos++)
  {
    crc ^= (uint)buf[pos];          // XOR byte into least sig. byte of crc

    for (int i = 8; i != 0; i--) {    // Loop over each bit
      if ((crc & 0x0001) != 0) {      // If the LSB is set
        crc >>= 1;                    // Shift right and XOR 0xA001
        crc ^= 0xA001;
      }
      else                            // Else LSB is not set
        crc >>= 1;                    // Just shift right
    }
  }
  // Note, this number has low and high bytes swapped, so use it accordingly (or swap bytes)
  return crc;
}
```

The problem is that I'm supposed to get two hex bytes as CRC numbers while this functions returns a integer value. For example, for "01" (1 byte), I was supposed to get a "7E80" while I get "21695", and I'm being unable to do some sort of conversion from this to that hex data.

My question, therefore, is: how do I go from the integer result to the double hex result needed? I tried a couple of options, with no success.

Note: I'm using Qt, so if one could find a solution implementing QByteArray or another Qt friendly code, I'll be glad. Either way a solution not using Qt, C or C++ is useless :P

Comment: Formatting, you're printing it as *decimal* instead of *hexadecimal*. Try e.g. `std::cout << std::hex << value << '\n';`. Although the decimal value `21695` is not the same as hexadecimal `0x7e80`.

Comment: Question is similar to **[this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19358246/crc-ccitt-to-crc16-modbus-implementation/19382244#19382244)**, but for a different programming language. However that still might be interesting to you if you wish to calculate CRC without using a table.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [MODBUS over serial line specification and implementation guide V1.02](http://modbus.org/docs/Modbus_over_serial_line_V1_02.pdf), the CRC is sent little-endian (low byte first).

I have no idea, though, how you came up with needing any hexadecimal bytes for the CRC. MODBUS RTU is a binary protocol, and the CRC is sent as two bytes, not as four hexadecimal digits!

Here's how you'd do it, using the CRC16 function you provided.

```
QByteArray makeRTUFrame(int slave, int function, const QByteArray & data) {
    Q_ASSERT(data.size() <= 252);
    QByteArray frame;
    QDataStream ds(&frame, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    ds.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian);
    ds << quint8(slave) << quint8(function);
    ds.writeRawData(data.constData(), data.size());
    int const crc = CRC16((BYTE*)frame.constData(), frame.size());
    ds << quint16(crc);
    return frame;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Well, not forgetting the need of a (BYTE*) before data.constData() in the CRC16 function, are you positive this function of yours works? :P I tried to test it against a Excel sheet from SimplyModbus.ca and I couldn't make the CRC values match (note: picking the resulting QByteArray and showing in the qdebug() as toHex()). I'm glad if you try it by youserlf :)

Comment: @Momergil: The CRC had to be calculated over the entire frame. I've edited the code to fix that. This demonstrates that you're trying to use code you don't understand in industrial automation settings. I hope nobody gets killed.

Comment: Haha, no worries there :) I was just wondering: in the Modbus protocolo one needs to mount the pack with: salve address (ok), command/function (ok) and then the register number and then the data - while your function only has the data. In this case, how should I insert this in your function? Only adding a <<quint8(register)? Note: I wasn't able to verify if the CRC is being done correctly by it as well. Just to be sure, did you check if your CRC calculation is working using e.g. Simply Modbus's CRC calculator? xD (I hope you didn't get mad for me asking that ^^)

Comment: @Momergil: You gave the function to use, it's not my job to check it for you. You can do it yourself. Similarly, the `data` parameter is the MODBUS payload that has register number and whatnot. You must be able to understand this code and modify it as you see fit. It's a starting point, not a finished solution. SO is not for free outsourcing.

Answer (score 10):

```
unsigned int CRC16_2(unsigned char *buf, int len)
{  
  unsigned int crc = 0xFFFF;
  for (int pos = 0; pos < len; pos++)
  {
  crc ^= (unsigned int)buf[pos];    // XOR byte into least sig. byte of crc

  for (int i = 8; i != 0; i--) {    // Loop over each bit
    if ((crc & 0x0001) != 0) {      // If the LSB is set
      crc >>= 1;                    // Shift right and XOR 0xA001
      crc ^= 0xA001;
    }
    else                            // Else LSB is not set
      crc >>= 1;                    // Just shift right
    }
  }

  return crc;
}
```

im kind of a noob myself, butttt-

i used the code u provided and tested it myself, and as u said it didnt work right, but then i realized it was passing  hex chars, so i just changed uint to char and  it checks out for me at least.

i even calculated a sample by hand to double check.

Comment: @Roney Thansk Roney for the answer, altough I'll end up using Kuba's version since I already validated it =]

Comment: @Momergil: it is Adam's answer. Roney was just slightly editing it.

Comment: Please don't use this code in production. There's no need to ever use such methods of CRC calculation except debugging.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar, interesting ... but why?

Comment: @MohammadKanan : Because it's slow due to processing the input data one bit at a time. This is, of course, invaluable if you're writing your own implementation and debugging since you can essentially look into the CRC output register at each step of the process. However, [this simple benchmark](https://gist.github.com/xavery/fb7ea088334091791b2ecf3c0d71e92d) shows that the bytewise version is 5 to 6 times faster on my machine. Even if you're in a very memory-constrained environment, sacrificing 512 bytes (in this particular case) of read-only memory can give you a large speedup.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar, Thanks for valuable information. The main motivation of my question, in fact is, I have seen this same piece of code used in a mature source code that I am using .. well, I didn't study its effect on speed and thus error rate .. I will.

Answer (score 2):

I tried using the first example of code you posted in here (the one using table) and I found out, that there is a mistake in using index. To make the code running correctly, you have to access to the table in the area limited by its size.

```
wCRCWord  ^= wCRCTable[(nTemp & 0xFF)];
```

So the whole code, that returns correct value of CRC16 for MODBUS is listed below. The number returned has already swaped Lo and Hi byte.

```
WORD CRC16 (const BYTE *nData, WORD wLength)
{
    static const WORD wCRCTable[] = {
    0x0000, 0xC0C1, 0xC181, 0x0140, 0xC301, 0x03C0, 0x0280, 0xC241,
    0xC601, 0x06C0, 0x0780, 0xC741, 0x0500, 0xC5C1, 0xC481, 0x0440,
    0xCC01, 0x0CC0, 0x0D80, 0xCD41, 0x0F00, 0xCFC1, 0xCE81, 0x0E40,
    0x0A00, 0xCAC1, 0xCB81, 0x0B40, 0xC901, 0x09C0, 0x0880, 0xC841,
    0xD801, 0x18C0, 0x1980, 0xD941, 0x1B00, 0xDBC1, 0xDA81, 0x1A40,
    0x1E00, 0xDEC1, 0xDF81, 0x1F40, 0xDD01, 0x1DC0, 0x1C80, 0xDC41,
    0x1400, 0xD4C1, 0xD581, 0x1540, 0xD701, 0x17C0, 0x1680, 0xD641,
    0xD201, 0x12C0, 0x1380, 0xD341, 0x1100, 0xD1C1, 0xD081, 0x1040,
    0xF001, 0x30C0, 0x3180, 0xF141, 0x3300, 0xF3C1, 0xF281, 0x3240,
    0x3600, 0xF6C1, 0xF781, 0x3740, 0xF501, 0x35C0, 0x3480, 0xF441,
    0x3C00, 0xFCC1, 0xFD81, 0x3D40, 0xFF01, 0x3FC0, 0x3E80, 0xFE41,
    0xFA01, 0x3AC0, 0x3B80, 0xFB41, 0x3900, 0xF9C1, 0xF881, 0x3840,
    0x2800, 0xE8C1, 0xE981, 0x2940, 0xEB01, 0x2BC0, 0x2A80, 0xEA41,
    0xEE01, 0x2EC0, 0x2F80, 0xEF41, 0x2D00, 0xEDC1, 0xEC81, 0x2C40,
    0xE401, 0x24C0, 0x2580, 0xE541, 0x2700, 0xE7C1, 0xE681, 0x2640,
    0x2200, 0xE2C1, 0xE381, 0x2340, 0xE101, 0x21C0, 0x2080, 0xE041,
    0xA001, 0x60C0, 0x6180, 0xA141, 0x6300, 0xA3C1, 0xA281, 0x6240,
    0x6600, 0xA6C1, 0xA781, 0x6740, 0xA501, 0x65C0, 0x6480, 0xA441,
    0x6C00, 0xACC1, 0xAD81, 0x6D40, 0xAF01, 0x6FC0, 0x6E80, 0xAE41,
    0xAA01, 0x6AC0, 0x6B80, 0xAB41, 0x6900, 0xA9C1, 0xA881, 0x6840,
    0x7800, 0xB8C1, 0xB981, 0x7940, 0xBB01, 0x7BC0, 0x7A80, 0xBA41,
    0xBE01, 0x7EC0, 0x7F80, 0xBF41, 0x7D00, 0xBDC1, 0xBC81, 0x7C40,
    0xB401, 0x74C0, 0x7580, 0xB541, 0x7700, 0xB7C1, 0xB681, 0x7640,
    0x7200, 0xB2C1, 0xB381, 0x7340, 0xB101, 0x71C0, 0x7080, 0xB041,
    0x5000, 0x90C1, 0x9181, 0x5140, 0x9301, 0x53C0, 0x5280, 0x9241,
    0x9601, 0x56C0, 0x5780, 0x9741, 0x5500, 0x95C1, 0x9481, 0x5440,
    0x9C01, 0x5CC0, 0x5D80, 0x9D41, 0x5F00, 0x9FC1, 0x9E81, 0x5E40,
    0x5A00, 0x9AC1, 0x9B81, 0x5B40, 0x9901, 0x59C0, 0x5880, 0x9841,
    0x8801, 0x48C0, 0x4980, 0x8941, 0x4B00, 0x8BC1, 0x8A81, 0x4A40,
    0x4E00, 0x8EC1, 0x8F81, 0x4F40, 0x8D01, 0x4DC0, 0x4C80, 0x8C41,
    0x4400, 0x84C1, 0x8581, 0x4540, 0x8701, 0x47C0, 0x4680, 0x8641,
    0x8201, 0x42C0, 0x4380, 0x8341, 0x4100, 0x81C1, 0x8081, 0x4040 };

    BYTE nTemp;
    WORD wCRCWord = 0xFFFF;

    while (wLength--)
    {
        nTemp = *nData++ ^ wCRCWord;
        wCRCWord >>= 8;
        wCRCWord  ^= wCRCTable[(nTemp & 0xFF)];
    }
    return wCRCWord;
} // End: CRC16
```

Comment: You said that *The number returned has already swapped Lo and Hi byte*. Are you sure about that for the presented code? I think this code returns regular CRC word, and a user has to swap bytes before concatenating to a message frame, as follows: `wCRCWord = (wCRCWord<<8) | (wCRCWord>>8)`. For example, consider a simple message in hex: `11 03 00 6B 00 03`. The CRC value calculated by this code for the considered frame is `87 76`, and the complete message is `11 03 00 6B 00 03 76 87` (example from here: http://www.simplymodbus.ca/ASCII.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Here are my two cents.
First thing you cant return two values to a function so

1. Append two values to the array(remember to remove const)
2. Return a struct containing these two values.
3. Proccess return value as follow

   ```
   WORD n = CRC16(nData,wLength);
   WORD x = (0xFF00&n)>>8,y=0x00FF&n;
   printf("0x%04x\n", n); // to check original value
   printf("0x%02x\t0x%02x\n",x,y); // to check separated values
   ```

Try this and let me know.